# Why receiving error 'should be push route with duplicated key' with Regact Native's NavigationExperimental?

Tags: react-native, redux, reactjs

My navigation reducer set up as such:

```
const {
  StateUtils: NavigationStateUtils
} = NavigationExperimental

const initialState = {
  index: 0,
  key: 'root',
  routes: [{
   key: 'login',
   title: 'Login',
   component: Login
  }]
}

function navigationState (state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {

    case PUSH_ROUTE:
      if (state.routes[state.index].key === (action.route && action.route.key)) return state
    return NavigationStateUtils.push(state, action.route)

    case POP_ROUTE:
      if (state.index === 0 || state.routes.length === 1) return state
      return NavigationStateUtils.pop(state)

   default:
     return state
  }
}
```

Then my button component triggers the action and navigates like so:

```
 handleBackAction() {
    if (this.props.navigation.index === 0) {
      return false
    }
    this.props.popRoute()
    return true
  }

  _handleNavigate(action) {
    switch (action && action.type) {
      case 'push':
        this.props.pushRoute(action.route)
        return true
      case 'back':
      case 'pop':
        return this._handleBackAction()
      default:
        return false
    }
  }

  _navigate(route){
    this.props._handleNavigate(route)
  }

  render(){
    const route = {
      type: 'push',
      route: {
        key: this.props.navKey,
        title: this.props.pageName,
        component: this.props.componentName
      }
    }

    return(
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this._navigate(route)}>
        <Text style={styles}>{pr.pageName}</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    )
```

How should I go about resolving the issue with NavigationStateUtils and in the reducer format that I provided?

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this happens when you try to push your 'login' route again on press of `TouchableHighlight`. Can you check if your route key (`this.props.navKey`) is 'login'.

So the answer is to not redirect to the same navigation route, instead use state to manage rendering.

Also, if you are just beginning, check how you can make your react components be pure functions and not classes ([egghead.io](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-the-single-immutable-state-tree) has a great tutorial on using connect from react-redux).

EDIT:

So after a lot of back and forth communication with you, I think I get what you are trying to achieve: you are trying to get the "tabbed behavior" with `NavigationExperimental` that is not built to do what you need out of the box. As I said, you need to **rephrase your question** a lot to match what you are trying to accomplish.

So, what you are trying to do is legit, but default "card stack" behavior that is taught in various tutorials is made to not allow you to do what you are trying to do for a reason: say you switch between 'login' and 'register' screens 4 times, and then press hardware back button: what is your expected behavior? Mine wouldn't be to go back and forth between 'login' and 'register' 4 times, but only once, like so: 'login' -> back -> 'register' -> back you're out of your app.

Reason I pose this question is because your answer will dictate how you write your own reducer for this behavior, because you will have to write your own reducer for your action, so besides `push` and `pop`, you will have, say, `tabSwitch` action, that will check if your scene is already pushed onto stack and pull it to the top of the stack, if you want the behavior I describe in the previous paragraph.

Comment: Yes it occurs if I press the button again. It is in fact 'login'. I checked it out but still can't seem to wrap my head around it. Could you show an example? So I can accept the answer as well.

Comment: I don't know from the example what you are trying to accomplish? Why are you pushing 'login' again, if you already have it in current state?

Comment: I am pushing to navigate to it but when I navigate to another route and try to navigate back I get the error. I want to be able to navigate back and forth.

Comment: Then, when wanting to go back, you need to use POP_ROUTE instead of PUSH_ROUTE. I think this will help you fix it.

Comment: Could you show an example of it? Because the navigation buttons are on a slide menu, so users would just be switching between routes rather than going back to it. So are you suggesting that I always pop the route after pushing it?

Comment: I still don't get your problem, why not disable the current route you are on, and allow only some way of going back, like back button. You got everything you need, I am not sure what you want me to show. It works like a stack, push->login, push->settings, pop, you are now on login, if you push->settings instead of pop, you get your error. Just don't do it.

Comment: What if I want to just keep switching between two routes. Say go to Route 1, then go to Route 2 directly, then switch to Route 1 again. There is back button involved. In that case, how can I implement is properly?

Comment: Checking to see if you've read my previous comment. Please let me know.

Comment: Have you had chance to check my comment?

Comment: Yes the navKey is login. How should I make it so that it is unique?

Comment: please let me figure this out. Been on it forever.

Comment: I was not by my computer for a couple of days. Do a PUSH_ROUTE for route 2, then POP_ROUTE, then do PUSH_ROUTE for route 2. You obviously have to handle back button on your own. Here is how to do it:
https://medium.com/@satya164/react-natives-navigationexperimental-with-redux-467acee02756#.xzzs57apd

Comment: No worries. Thanks for getting back! Just to clarify, so just POP_ROUTE right after PUSH_ROUTE is triggered?

Comment: Yep, routes work like a stack, you push route when you want to get to it, and you pop it when you want to go back.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll give it a try! Before I accept the answer, just a quick question, is that how Navigation Tab Bars work? When you go from one tab and click on another tab to go to another view, does it push and pop right away? But doesn't this issue have more to do with `key` rather than `index`? Thanks Dejan!

Comment: You are confusing me constantly, I don't remember mentioning `index`, and don't remember you mentioning Tabs. However, it's up to you to implement custom actions and reducers for tabs, so it does what ever you told it to do. Probably you told it to push all the time, and you click on the same tab after a couple of clicks and it pushes the same screen again, which causes the crash. If you want tabs, don't push the current state on the stack, but do pop and then push, so you'll have a clean stack - update your reducer. If I understood right, please update your question with info about tabs.

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication. I used Tabs as an example to the navigation slide menu with buttons that I have. I tried the push() and pop() right after, but I am still getting the same error. I mentioned `index` because that relates to push() and pop() issue that you presented, but the real issue is that somehow every time a route gets pushed, it needs to have a unique 'key' every time? But that seem so hacky..

Comment: Checking in to see if you've my last comment again. Thanks Dejan!

Comment: Sorry, I think you need to provide detailed information on what you are doing. I have told you what I know, and you seem to be ignorant on the fact you can't push 'login' twice on the routes structure that works like a stack. My best guess is you should make sure there is no 'login' route on your routes state when you do push second time, and you keep telling me that you want to push the same route twice, but I can't grasp your reasons. I hope you get more info or you find another solution.

Comment: I have edited my response with the latest understanding of your problem.

Comment: First and foremost, really appreciate you for reaching out once more to help. Unfortunately, no luck so far on my end... Please take a looking at the original post with an image of Slide Menu that I am trying to implement for further clarification and to serve as an example to the case you posed. Say you clicked on `Notification` button on the Slide Menu as shown in the image, then it would not have a hardware back button, and the same would go for `Member` button and so on for all the buttons on it.

Comment: But say you click the `Notification` button, hide the Slide Menu and continue on the `Notification` page and navigate on it, then the hardware back button would appear. For the Slide Menu buttons, would what I am describing be more of `.replace` of Navigator?

Comment: Yeah, the other way to implement your reducer is a combination of `NavigationStateUtils` pop and push, which would do a replace (which I also suggested earlier, if you remember, but i think you did push first, instead of pop). I only gave you one example, but it's important that you get that it's up to you to implement and use the reducer you want when you want it, so if there is a back button, you will use pop, when navigation is out you will use replace, when you are navigating deeper into your app, you use standard push, and you avoid pushing the same scene twice.

Comment: Appreciate the response again and definitely. So is pop and push considered a .replace? I still can't seem to wrap my head around how to get .replace working. Do you mind showing an example?

Comment: Add the following to your reducer:
`case REPLACE:
      const s = NavigationStateUtils.pop(state);
      return NavigationStateUtils.push(s, action.route);`
You might want some safety checks, and adding the `REPLACE` action, but this is the example.